# Does AWS CloudWatch affect Instance Performance (CPU/Memory)

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have a running application on a Linux EC-2 instance and I would like to set the CloudWatch Agent.
I would like to know what are the CloudWatch Agent using CPU/Memory/Disk to what extent in order to collect the information.

Its a minor concern but still would like to know if Agent will affect the instance performance (Is it a minimal impact?).

Thanks in advance!

Golan

Answer (score 1):

*Anything* that runs on a computer would impact performance. It is always a trade-off between running some code and the benefit that the code provides.

The Agent only collects data at regular intervals, so it should not have a large impact on the system.

I suggest you install CloudWatch Agent and measure the impact yourself.